# Platform specific height and width in appcelerator

Tags: dynamic, height, width, appcelerator, platform-specific

I want to change the height and width of the images dynamically according to various platforms.

I have checked the documentation for platform.height and platform.width of appcelerator. But I cannot seem to understand how it is done.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this cross-platform code to get Android/iOS devices width & height in dp.

***alloy.js***

```
var df = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor;
var w = OS_IOS ? Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth : Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth / df;
var h = OS_IOS ? Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight : Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight / df;

Alloy.Globals.deviceWidth = Math.min(w, h);
Alloy.Globals.deviceHeight = Math.max(w, h);
```

now you can use these global variables in any file you want like this:

```
"#someLabel": {
   width : Alloy.Globals.deviceWidth,
   height : 100
}
```